# How can I extract all instances of a key from a list within a python dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, boto, boto3

I have a python dictionary named 'available_volumes'.
This dictionary contains a key 'Volumes', and within this key a list of 'VolumeIds.' How can I print each of the 'VolumeId's within this list?

Here is some simplified sample data for my 'available_volumes' data:

```
{'Volumes': 
  [
    {'VolumeId': 'vol-0fdfe004dgte6e8385d'},
    {'VolumeId': 'vol-0fdfe344d35te6e858f'},
    {'VolumeId': 'vol-0fwde024d4gte6e834g'}
  ]
}
```

If I take my 'available_volumes' dictionary and run the following on it:

```
myIds = available_volumes ['Volumes'][0]['VolumeId']
```

I can get the first VolumeId which is at index 0. However, how do I iterate and print all of the VolumeIds?

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Comment: @MooingRawr added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply iterate over the list:

```
for vol in available_volumes['Volumes']:
    print(vol['VolumeId'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `['Volumes']` to lookup the list of *VolumeId* dictionaries.  Then use a for-loop to loop over the list of dicts.  Then use `d['VolumeId']` to extract the actual values from the inner dicts:

```
>>> available_volumes = {'Volumes': 
  [
    {'VolumeId': 'vol-0fdfe004dgte6e8385d'},
    {'VolumeId': 'vol-0fdfe344d35te6e858f'},
    {'VolumeId': 'vol-0fwde024d4gte6e834g'}
  ]
}
>>> for d in available_volumes['Volumes']:
        print(d['VolumeId'])


vol-0fdfe004dgte6e8385d
vol-0fdfe344d35te6e858f
vol-0fwde024d4gte6e834g
```